# Outlets linked to controls in a Static TableView are not initialized

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, reactive-cocoa-3

I am trying to setup a master details navigation.
I use storyboard, master is a dynamic table and details is a static table.
[image: storyboard]
I have a nameLabel setup as an outlet in the controller but when i try to access it in viewDidLoad, its still set to nil.

Instead of using prepareForSegue, I have used didSelectRowAtIndexPath which pushes the detail view like this: (because i'm using the TableViewBindingHelper, see https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/ReactiveTwitterSearch/tree/master/ReactiveTwitterSearch/Util)

```
    func showLessonView(lessonVM: LessonViewModel) {

        let lessonViewController = LessonViewController(WithViewModel: lessonVM)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lessonViewController, animated: true)

    }
```

LessonViewController:

```
import Foundation
import ReactiveCocoa

class LessonViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var lessonNameLabel: UILabel!

private var viewModel: LessonViewModel

init(WithViewModel viewModel: LessonViewModel){
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bindData()
}

func bindData() {
    // null here!
    if (lessonNameLabel != nil) {
        lessonNameLabel.rac_text <~ viewModel.name
    }
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Other sample code i have seen performs the navigation in segue which ends up calling the init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) constructor and all the outlets are already initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you initialise the view controller with the `WithViewModel` initialiser, it knows nothing about the storyboard and so the outlets are not hooked up.  To get the outlets hooked up as specified in the storyboard, you need either to use a segue, or to use the storyboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier:)` method to create the view controller.  Either way, you can't (easily) pass the ViewModel as an argument for the initialisation, so you will need to expose the viewModel var (remove `private`) and set it separately in your `showLessonView` method.  To use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier:)`, give your `Lesson View Controller` an identifier (say "LessonViewController") in the storyboard.  Then amend your `showLessonView` as follows:

```
func showLessonView(lessonVM: LessonViewModel) {
    let lessonViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier:"LessonViewController") as! LessonViewController
    lessonViewController.viewModel = lessonVM
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lessonViewController, animated: true)
}
```

When a view controller is instantiated from a storyboard, the `init(coder:)` initialiser is used, so either remove the override of that method, or amend it to call the super implementation:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```